# r: A column disappears and other columns' names turn to Xs

Tags: r, cosine-similarity, adjacency-matrix

I've got a piece of code and I don't quite understand how it works. I'm sorry if I may sound stupid...
I'm making a network, so I created an adjacency matrix that looks like this:
[Part of my adjacency matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uAUR.png)

So, when I try to calculate cosine similarity via lsa::cosine function the column "authors$book_id" disappears and all the other columns' names that contain authors' IDs are replaced with Xs.
My code is this:

```
a_cos <- lsa::cosine(t(as.matrix(adj_matrix[, -1]))) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  +0.01 %>%
  round()
```

This is what this code returns:
[After lsa::cosine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lh1vC.png)
Since I know this is isn't an error I want to know how this happened.
Can someone please explain to me what this piece of code does and why it removes the first column (book IDs) completely and turns authors' IDs to Xs? How can I apply lsa::cosine so that this doesn't happen?
I'm only a beginner, but I really need help and I will appreciate any comments! This is my first question on stackoverflow, I hope I've described the problem extensively enough...

Comment: It looks like your input data doesn't have row names. So after you `t()` transpose it, that means it doesn't have column names. When a matrix without column names is converted to a data frame, the default column names are `X1`, `X2`, .... Try `matrix(1:4, 2) %>% data.frame` to see.

Comment: As for "why it removes the first column completely", R indexes `data[rows, columns]` and uses negative indices to drop rows/columns. So the code snippet `adj_matrix[, -1]` is explicitly telling R "drop the first column!". The IDs (presumably) are unique identifiers and don't have anything to do with the similarity.

Comment: When you don't know what code does, I'd **strongly** recommend giving yourself a small example and looking at each piece. Start with just a few rows and columns `test = adj_matrix[1:4, 1:5]`, and run `test[, -1]`, then `as.matrix(test[, -1])` then `t(as.matrix(test[, -1]))`, etc., so that you can see and understand each step.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! I'm going to try to make it work somehow...